# Robustness of doubling dimension to small perturbations

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computer-science, computational-geometry

Let $M$ be a metric space. Then the [*doubling dimension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_space) of $M$, denoted $\dim M$, is defined to be the minimum value $k$ such that every ball in $M$ of radius $r$ can be covered by at most $2^k$ balls of radius $r/2$.

In the paper ["Small Hop-diameter Sparse Spanners for Doubling Metrics"](https://web.archive.org/web/20231219144800/https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eanupamg/papers/soda06-hop.pdf) by Chan/Gupta, the authors write:

> Apart from being a generalization of the $\ell_p$ notion of dimension,
> designing algorithms that only use the doubling properties (instead of
> the geometry of $\mathbb R^k$) has other advantages: the notion of doubling
> dimension is fairly resistant to small perturbations in the distances:
> **for instance, if one takes a distance matrix of a set of points in $\ell_p^k$ and slightly changes some of the entries, then the doubling
> dimension does not change by much,** but the metric may not remain
> isometrically embeddable in $\ell_p$ (into any number of dimensions).

I have two related questions about this statement.

1. Is there a known formalization of this stability, perhaps with respect to the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) on (finite) subsets of $\ell_p^k$? That is, do we have something like the following: Let $A$ and $B$ be finite subsets of $\ell_p^k$. Then $\lvert\dim A - \dim B\rvert \leq d_\text H(A,B)$, where $d_\text H$ is the Hausdorff distance?
2. Does this stability generalize to arbitrary finite metric spaces, with respect to, e.g., the [Gromov–Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_convergence#Gromov%E2%80%93Hausdorff_distance)? That is, if $A$ and $B$ are finite metric spaces, do we have something like $\lvert\dim A - \dim B\rvert \leq d_\text{GH}(A,B)$, where $d_\text{GH}$ is the Gromov–Hausdorff distance?

If 'No' to the above, are there any sensible formalizations of Chan & Gupta's statement that make their claim of stability precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that my questions $1$ and $2$ can be seen to be false by considering simple examples in $\mathbb R$. Morally, since doubling dimension takes only integer values, a general stability result is not possible in the sense that I describe.

However, after further reading, I believe what Chan & Gupta are referring to is the robustness result given as Propsition $3$ in ["Bypassing the Embedding"](https://web.archive.org/web/20240102084556/http://kunaltalwar.org/papers/bypass.pdf) by Talwar:

> **Proposition 3**
> [Robustness]. Let $(X, d)$ and $(Y, d')$ be metric spaces such that there is a bijective map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ satisfying $d\left(x_1, x_2\right) \leq$ $d' \left(f\left(x_1\right), f\left(x_2\right)\right) \leq D \cdot d\left(x_1, x_2\right)$. Then $k_Y \leq 2 k_X \cdot\lceil\log 4 D\rceil$.

Note that Talwar denotes the doubling dimension of $X$ by $k_{X}$.